# Sublime text 3 build Jade into .php

Tags: php, pug, sublimetext3

I am trying out jade and I am trying to work with jade within sublime text 3.

I already have it working to render the index.html file.

I am trying to run a custom builder that will spit out a .php file instead. I appreciate your help.

Current custom build is:

```
{
   "cmd": ["cmd", "/c", "jade", "$file", "--pretty"],
   "selector": "source.jade"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define a custom compile function in a separate js file and invoke the Jade's Javascript API to do the compilation. More info: https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/1645

But here's a simple workaround: just rename the file

```
"shell": true,
"cmd": ["jade", "$file", "--pretty", "&", "ren $file_base_name.html $file_base_name.php"],
```

Also notice that I removed `"cmd", "/c",` and added `"shell": true` which does the same thing.

More info on Sublime build system: http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use the `--extension` parameter.

Create file `\SublimeText\Data\Packages\User\Pug2php.sublime-build` with this content.

```
{
    "shell": true,
    "cmd": ["pug", "$file", "--pretty", "--extension","php"]
}
```

I use Pug-Cli for that https://github.com/pugjs/pug-cli